# WPF Canvas does not render Shapes that are bound to the ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I create Polygons in code that get added to an generic ObservableList. That is my ViewModel.

```
class CanvasViewModel : ModelBase
{
    private WpfObservableRangeCollection<Shape> CanvasShapes { get; set; }
//...
}
```

The Shape are proper WPF shapes. No container or anything. Furthermore I set the Style of these shapes also programmatically, as an example:

```
public void ApplyStyle(Style style)
    {
        style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Shape.FillProperty, Brushes.DodgerBlue));
    }
```

As you can see, I am definitely setting a color to these shapes.
My issue is that in my program, when I start it, the canvas gets rendered (I can see it when I set the background of the canvas to any color) but none of the shapes I add to the ObservableRangeCollection (they are definitely in the collection.)

Here's the Page code for the CanvasPage:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasShapes}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

I figure since these are proper WPF shapes that I don't need to add any DataTemplates to them or anything, however I think this is where I'm mistaken.

And here's the CodeBehind of the Window that currently initializes these functions (I know this is bad practice, it's just to get the programm running for testing purposes):

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CanvasPage canvasPage = new CanvasPage()
        //boilerplate...
        var canvasViewModel = new CanvasViewModel(...);
        canvasPage.DataContext = canvasViewModel;
        this._NavigationFrame?.Navigate(canvasPage);
    }
```

Here's a MCV version of this issue:

Viewmodel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MVCE
{
    class ViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Shape> CanvasShapes;

        public ViewModel()
        {
            CanvasShapes = new ObservableCollection<Shape>();
            var polygon = new Polygon();
            var pointCollection = new PointCollection
            {
                new Point(100, 100),
                new Point(100, -100),
                new Point(-100, -100),
                new Point(-100, 100)
            };
            polygon.Points = pointCollection;
            Style style = new Style();
            style.Setters.Add( new Setter(Shape.FillProperty, Brushes.Aquamarine));

            polygon.Style = style;
            CanvasShapes.Add(polygon);
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.cs

```
<Window x:Class="MVCE.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVCE"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <DockPanel>
        <Frame x:Name="_NavigationFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MVCE
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
            var page = new Page1();
            page.DataContext = viewModel;
            _NavigationFrame.Navigate(page);
        }
    }
}
```

CanvasPage.xaml (.cs file is default)

```
<Page x:Class="MVCE.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MVCE"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Page1">

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CanvasShapes}" Background="Brown">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Page>
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including the actual shapes that you add to the source collection.

Comment: I copied your code, except for ApplyStyle(). In the CanvasViewModel constructor, I added an Ellipse to CanvasShapes with width and height of 20 and Fill = Brushes.DodgerBlue. I ran it and saw a 20x20 blue ellipse in MainWindow. Your MVCE should include all the code involved in setting the visual properties of the shapes, **with particular emphasis on the parts that you can safely assure us are working perfectly**. You'd be better off having a collection of a viewmodel type and creating/styling the shapes in XAML, but it's your life.

Comment: @EdPlunkett as asked by mm8, I added an MCVE to the bottom of the post. I hope I didn't forget anything.

Comment: Do you have any plans for that `PointCollection`?

Comment: Oops, yes, it was supposed to be assigned to the Polygon... one moment please.

Comment: Right. That's the problem.

Comment: BTW, an MVCE can usually omit the using lines and `///` boilerplate comments

Comment: Sadly it isn't. It's still not rendering anything on my screen. Only the "brown" background, but no shape to be seen anywhere.

Comment: `ViewModel.CanvasShapes` is a field. It needs to be a property with a `get` (and optionally a `set`). You can't bind to a field.

Comment: That fixed it for the MVCE. Strange, because my proper solution has the get; set; properties, but it doesn't work. It seems I'll have to do some more digging what exactly is different from the MVCE. No matter that, thank you anyways, it's already quite uplifting to know that my approach _can_ work.

Comment: Excellent. Shouldn't be too much trouble now that you've got a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I figured it out.**

The issue was that my ObservableCollection in my ViewModel was set to private. Due to this, the DataBinding seemed to have issues. I thought it would work due to reflection, but I was mistaken. **Setting the collection to public fixed it right away.**